# How to add response body to Html

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have somthing like that

```
var myArticle = document.querySelector('article');
myArticle.innerHTML = res.text('legacy').toString();
```

This return only some string.

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAcQAAAIXCAYAAAACHS4DAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6....
```

how to do that also display some tag in html for example like this.

```
 <typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040" />
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.13.10.1.1" />
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.13.10.1.2" />
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.13.10.1.4" />
```

Comment: Can you explain it more please

Comment: Rajesh Murugan I have response from server and it's xml and i would like display in some html elemnt.

Comment: Try this myArticle.textContent = res.text('legacy').toString();

Comment: @Rajesh Murugan thanks it's working